# How did Mississippi regain representation without ratifying the 13th amendment?

Tags: slavery, american-civil-war, civil-rights, us-congress

I read that Congress [required former Confederate states to ratify the 13th amendment in order to regain representation in the federal government](https://www.history.com/topics/black-history/thirteenth-amendment), but Mississippi didn't ratify it until 1995 and not officially until 2013.  I know they regained representation before they voted to ratify the 13th amendment in 1995. How did they regain representation in the government before 1995?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Looks like it was merely a [clerical issue](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2013/02/19/172432523/after-snafu-mississippi-ratifies-amendment-abolishing-slavery)

Comment: Didn't we have a question about MS. and the 13th before?